# Return result for each Select Case option if count is 0 or rows not found

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

TSQL 2008r2.  I would like this query to alwasy return three rows.  One for each item specified in the SELECT CASE :

```
SELECT CASE result 
WHEN 'A' then 'Group A' 
WHEN 'B' then 'Group B' 
WHEN 'C' then 'Group C' 
end as resultType, count(Result) as numberOfResults from masterGroups 
where theYear=2016 and postCode=3579 group by result;
```

ATM it correctly returns this:

```
Group A    1
Group C    8
```

I would like it to always return three rows regardless of what it finds in masterGroups.  If one of the three items is not found I would like it to return 0. So in the above case it should return this:

```
Group A    1
Group B    8
Group C    0
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want here is a table which contains all the result types.  In the absence of this, we may use an on-the-fly CTE for this purpose:

```
WITH results AS (
    SELECT 'A' AS result UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C'
)

SELECT
    CASE r.result 
        WHEN 'A' THEN 'Group A' 
        WHEN 'B' THEN 'Group B' 
        WHEN 'C' THEN 'Group C' 
    END AS resultType,
    COUNT(m.result) AS numberOfResults
FROM results r
LEFT JOIN masterGroups m
    ON r.result = m.result AND m.theYear = 2016 AND m.postCode = 3579
GROUP BY
    r.result;
```

Note: Move the logic in your current `WHERE` clause to the `ON` condition of the left join.

Comment: You are quicker shooter ;)

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Funny you say this, because if Gordon Linoff were out, he would have posted several minutes before I did :-)

Comment: mmmmm I get the same result.  Sorry I made an error in the initial post result.  I said the result was  Group A   1 and Group B   8.  I should have said the result is  Group A    1 and Group C    8.  I have corrected this in the initial post now

Comment: @Mat41 Sorry, I should have moved the logic in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the join.  Easy mistake to make without seeing your data.

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve the same by the following code

```
SELECT CASE groups 
    WHEN 'A' then 'Group A' 
    WHEN 'B' then 'Group B' 
    WHEN 'C' then 'Group C' 
    END AS resultType, 
    COUNT(Result) AS numberOfResults 
FROM (VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C')) r (groups)
LEFT JOIN masterGroups m ON m.Result = r.groups
    AND theYear=2016 AND postCode=3579 
GROUP BY groups
```

**OR**

```
FROM (SELECT 'A' UNION SELECT 'B' UNION SELECT 'C') r (groups)
LEFT JOIN masterGroups m ON m.Result = r.groups
    AND theYear=2016 AND postCode=3579 
GROUP BY groups
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT`:

```
select resultType,numberOfResults
from
(
select 'numresults' numresults,[A]'Group A',[B] 'Group B',[C] 'Group c'
from
( 
select result from masterGroups where theYear=2016 and postCode=3579
)as source
pivot
(
count(result) for result in ([A],[B],[C])
)as p
)ss
unpivot
(
numberOfResults
for resultType in ([Group A], [Group B], [Group c])
)up
```